# Using 'include?' to check if there is a space in a string

Tags: ruby

I am testing whether a name `@fm1` has a space (because dog does not have a surname).

```
def family_member?
  if @fm1.include?(" ")
    puts @fm1.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ") + " is a puppy!"
  elsif @fm1.include?("schnider")
    puts @fm1.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ") + " is Schnider's member."
  else
    puts @fm1.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ") + " is a guest."
  end
end
```

When I do `if @fm1.include?(" ")`, it shows the result after `else`. I would like to know if there is any method. Can you help me finish this?

Comment: Note: `then` is something that's really not used in Ruby as it's basically clutter.

Comment: Obligatory [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) link. I know of dogs named things like "Sir Scratchybutt" and people have names like "Sting" or "Bono". Careful when making these assumptions.

Comment: @tadman, except, for example, `x = 1; case x; when 1 then 'hi'; when 2 then 'ho'; end`, `then` being required.

Comment: @CarySwoveland People who one-line their case statements will have to deal with the angry wrath of tools like Rubocop!

Comment: @tadman, I can live with that. I sometimes find Robocop to more like Persnicketycop or Oldpersonishcop (formerly Oldwomanishcop).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sometimes you have to break the rules, but it's nice having tools like that to tell new developers what the rules are.

Comment: I cannot get at all what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most Ruby way to do this is with `case` and regular expressions:

```
def family_member_text
  name = @fm1.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")

  case (@fm1)
  when /\s/
    "#{name} is a puppy!"
  when /schnider/i
    "#{name} is Schnider's member."
  else
    "#{name} is a guest."
  end
end
```

Where this method returns text that you can, but are not obligated to feed to `puts`, something that leads to more modular code design. Remember your [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Note that I've also applied DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) here to clean up the duplicated name canonicalization code. That's also probably wrong because names like "Leonardo da Vinci" do not have a capital "Da".

Comment: Thank you! the problem was just solved, quite and clean.